# Remove braces formatting in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just installed VS 2015 and I love all it has to offer, but some of the formatting options still seem to be evading me. The most annoying of which is the below example of spacing that is automatically added when using braces.

```
class HelloWorld { }
static void main(string[] args) { }
```

I'd prefer this:

```
class HelloWorld{}
static void main(string[] args){}
```

Is there any way to change this without 3rd party extensions?

Comment: Are you referring to the space _between_ the braces?

Comment: @ispiro that, as well as the space before them

Comment: I just checked Tools-options-text editor-c#-formatting-spacing and I can't find anything for that. But I'll just mention that I actually find it handy so that if at some point I want to add something there (at least between the braces) it's easier to click there. But YMMV of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> Spacing -> Set Spacing for Brackets
```

Comment: Do you might have installed ReSharper by any means?

Answer (score 0):

@Mio Bambino's answer is only for square brackets unfortunately, the only way I have found to prevent automatically formatting {} is to go to

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> General
```

and possibly untick the following:

- Automatically format completed block on }
- Automatically format on on paste